# I am working on a project in which i am inserting data in Gujarati language but when i retrieve the data by datatable it display encoded data

Tags: json, datatable

[Data table value shows ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKRCz.jpg)I am working on a project in which I am inserting data in Gujarati language but when I retrieve the data by datatable it displays encoded data.[Database value stored correctly...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4m4.jpg)

In database contain Gujarati value but while showing in data tables it displays like.

```
$table = 'circular';

$primaryKey = 'id';


mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET character_set_result='utf8',character_set_client='utf8',character_set_connection='utf8',character_set_database='utf8',character_set_server='utf8'");

$columns = array(

 array( 'db' => 'id',  'dt' => 0 ),
 array('db' =>"subject",'dt'=>1),

);

$sql_details = array(
 'user' => 'root',
 'pass' => '',
 'db'   => 'qwe',
 'host' => 'localhost',
 'charset'=>'utf8'

);

require( 'vendor/DataTables/server-side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
 SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, 'id>=1')
);

?>
```

Comment: So you can query the data in DB and that is Gujarati, but when you fetch the same data it's different. It has to do with php adapter that you are using, also post (image) what data you are inserting and what's the result

Comment: Please check borh images in quetion. Please help to resolve this issue we are trying to solve it more then two days still not getting any result from anywhere.@ Mrinal Kamboj